# Is there a way to delete uploaded files after stopping the execution of code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a file upload system in python flask where the uploaded files are stored in a folder. I edit my code on VSCODE. It is a hassle to delete the files after every time I stop the code, so I made it so that when I go to the home page of my flask application, it deletes the files. However, I often forget to do that and the files are left undeleted and cause problems.

So...
Is there any setting or extension on VSCODE that I can use to auto delete files when I forcefully stop my program from running?

Comment: First task in the code is to clear the folder, quickest way we found was to remove the folder and replace it.

Comment: which files do you upload, and where to do you upload, which code do you edit with VSC and why do you need to delete the uploaded files each time

Comment: have you looked at the [postDebugTask attribute](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes) of your launch config, it you use a task to start the code look at the compound tasks

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.
You have two models to handle the app termination:
Module [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/atexit.html) which it is not called when using Ctrl+C, for that there is a module called [signal](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/signal.html)

```
import atexit
#defining function to run on shutdown
def close_running_threads():
for thread in the_threads:        thread.join()
print "Threads complete, ready to finish"
#Register the function to be called on exit
atexit.register(close_running_threads)
#start your process
app.run()
```

There is a nice explanation and snippet related to signal [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70455033/how-to-process-sigterm-and-still-have-a-working-process-terminate)

Comment: since when will this snippet run

Comment: atexit triggers when closing the app or VS but NOT with CTRL+C signal triggers everytime the process is killed no matter how

Comment: that I understand, but have you copy/paste your snippet and try to run